# Decrypted zip file is invalid can't open it

Tags: c#, .net, encryption

My problem is that the created encrypted zip file is unable to open after decrypting it. It says the compressed file is invalid. File it self almost doubled it's initial space after decrypting from 15 KB to 27 KB. The problem occours on zip files, when I encrypted and decryped a xml file it worked just fine. Below my whole code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace EDI
{
public class EncryptionHelper
{
    public void Main()
    {
        var file = @"C:\Temp\test.zip";

        AesCryptoServiceProvider AES = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
        AES.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        AES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        AES.BlockSize = 128;
        AES.KeySize = 128;

        AES.GenerateKey();
        AES.GenerateIV();

        var key = AES.Key;
        var iv = AES.IV;

        encryptAES(AES, file, key, iv);
        decryptAES(AES, file + ".encrypted", key, iv);
    }
    public void encryptAES(SymmetricAlgorithm algo, string filePath, byte[] key, byte[] IV)
    {
        using (FileStream fin = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            using (FileStream fout = new FileStream(filePath + ".encrypted", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                using (ICryptoTransform crypt = algo.CreateEncryptor(key, IV))
                {
                    using (CryptoStream crStream = new CryptoStream(fout, crypt, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        fin.CopyTo(crStream);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public void decryptAES(SymmetricAlgorithm algo, string filePath, byte[] key, byte[] IV)
    {
        using (FileStream fStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            using (ICryptoTransform crypt = algo.CreateDecryptor(key, IV))
            {
                using (CryptoStream crStream = new CryptoStream(fStream, crypt, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(crStream))
                    {
                        string data = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        File.WriteAllText(filePath.Replace(".encrypted", ".restored"), data);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Edit to show the fix.

```
 using (FileStream writer = new FileStream(filePath + ".decrypted", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
 // using (Read reader = new StreamReader(crStream))
 {
 //  string data = reader.ReadToEnd();
 // File.WriteAllText(filePath.Replace(".encrypted", ".restored"), data);
     crStream.CopyTo(writer);
 }
```

Comment: `File.WriteAllText` -> You need to write binary data, not text.

Comment: Is a ZIP file Text?  Try using a different method for writing : File.WriteAllText()

Comment: `encryptAES` uses two `FileStream` objects, and then `fin.CopyTo`. But `decryptAES` uses only one `FileStream` and one `StreamReader` and then `File.WriteAllText`. That's not the same.

Comment: My fault, changed StreamReader to FileStream and it works fine now

Comment: Encryption should work for any arbitrary data. So it is a good idea to write a unit test that generates random data in a few different sizes and check that the decrypted data is identical. This will be made easier if the input/output are streams rather than file-Paths. Add an overload that takes file-paths and delegates the implementation to the stream-overload if you want to.